# iOS FaceTime: Programmatically check if a contact is FaceTime-able using C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, facetime

I am working o n an ios app (let's call it: Titanic) using Xamarin (C#). The functionality I am trying to develop at the moment is FaceTime from within Titanic.

My questions is: How can I programmatically determine if a contact is facetime-able? i.e. how can Titanic figure out if a contact can actually receive a call through FaceTime? At the moment, when a contact is not facetime-able, Titanic would just try to initiate the facetime call and shows a grey screen and then snaps back to the app. I need to be able to predetermine whether to allow facetime to be initiated BEFORE the above happens.

Comment: Please visit and read this page on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not very possible with the iOS SDK. While it may be possible to test with something such as

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new Foundation.NSUrl("facetime://0000000000"));
```

However, that does not account for whether or not the contact has disable FaceTime, and further more is not 100% accurate.

Hope this helps!